# Detect object direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help with detecting, which direction my game-object is facing. My game-object is a cube that looks forward from the beginning with the Y-axis 0 (the blue arrow is pointing forward). When playing the game, the cube will be rotating its Y-axis by 90 degrees sometimes. Then I need to know if the cube looks forward, right, left or back using an if statement. Example: `if (cube looks right, left, back or forward){ //Do something ... }`

By the way, the cube can rotate so that the Y-axis is +something and -something.

I hope that I was clear, ask me if I wasn't, thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Please share your code as well in order to help us understand what you've done so far. Otherwise it will be so difficult to answer your question. Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to edit your post and make it better.

Comment: Isn't there a velocity property of your object?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the 3d object pointing by using his rotation, heres what code i have made

```
 if(gameObject.transform.rotation.y <= 45 && gameObject.transform.rotation.y >= -45)
{
//whatever code when this 3d cuberube pointed forward
}

 if(gameObject.transform.rotation.y <= 145 && gameObject.transform.rotation.y >= 45)
{
//whatever code when this 3d cuberube pointed left
}


 if(gameObject.transform.rotation.y >= -145 && gameObject.transform.rotation.y <= -45)
{
//whatever code when this 3d cuberube pointed right
}



 if(gameObject.transform.rotation.y > 145 && gameObject.transform.rotation.y < -145)
{
//whatever code when this 3d cuberube pointed back
}
```

Remember this code only usable if you mean the 3d-objects body pointing,
if you need the pointings of an object that counting on your camera(not an object body) that code wont help.

Freeze and look forward, Artyom!